# How can I capture combined kernel and userspace stacks with perf

Tags: linux-kernel, perf

I'm trying to capture combined user and kernel stacks with perf, so I can see which user space code produces are particular kernel call chain.
Basically I want to create a flamegraph looking like this:[image: flamegraph]

Unfortunately all my kernel stacks end at `entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath` and there is no connection to the userspace stacks.

I'm using `perf record -g --call-graph dwarf -F 99 --pid 12345` to capture. I have debug symbols for the kernel, libc and my program.
This is kernel 4.8.14 on a Fedora 25 system.

Comment: I presume you are following the steps mentioned [**here**](http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html#FlameGraphs). Can you double check that the value you are passing to `--pid` matches the pid of the process you are trying to profile? Also is the process running (or simply sleeping) when the profiling data is captured?

Comment: I did use the instructions from the link and the pid is correct. I can see the stacks from my application just fine (and it's not sleeping all the time). The problem is that all the kernel stacks sit on top of entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath whichs sits on top of the lowest bar of the graph (named after the executable) instead of sitting on top of the userspace stack which made the syscall.

Answer (score 0):

Try `bcc` utilities that use `BPF` technology. Take a look at `profile` util.

https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md